# Add Swagger documentation for DTO properties

Tags: c#, swagger

I'm using methods in my WebAPI that take in parameters.
I can provide descriptions in my Swagger UI for the basic parameters (id and terminology) using the following 'param' XML Comments:

```
    /// <param name="terminology">terminology comment goes here</param>
    /// <param name="id">id comment goes here</param>
    /// <param name="filterDto"></param>
    /// <returns>The results</returns>
    [HttpGet("{terminology}/product/{id}/details")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IPacksResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorsDto), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public IActionResult GetProductPacks(
        [FromRoute] string terminology,
        [FromRoute] string id,
        [FromQuery] GetPackByIdFilteredDto filterDto)
```

However, what I need help with is... The 3rd parameter being passed in (filterDto) is a class with several  properties which also appear in the Swagger UI, but I don't know how to create descriptions for each of those inputs:

```
public class GetPackByIdFilteredDto
{
    public string Dt { get; set; }
    public string Dc { get; set; }
    public string Ms { get; set; }
```

Comment: Classes and properties can have XML documentation comments as well. Try typing `///` above the query or property. Visual Studio will expand this to a basic XML comment. XML comments aren't specific to Swagger

Comment: Great stuff thanks! It really is that simple. Works a treat.